# Color correcting/balancing for mosaic in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, color, mosaic

I have about a hundred of individually georefered RGB aerial images which I'd like to mosaic to have a nice, seamless final raster. I need a method to make the mosaic lines as invisible as possible. l Here is a pic:

[image]

I tried simply mosaic it, but lines would be clearly visible like above. The best result so far is with mosaic color correction, with dodging, color grid option:

[image]

But it's still not the best.

I tried ERDAS Imagine MosaicPro with dodging and or color correcting, but didn't get an acceptable result.

Is there a way to do a good looking mosaic in ArcGIS for Desktop?

I have an Advanced level license available.

Comment: As far as i can see from your snapshots, the second result looks pretty satisfactory. I presume the bottom swath was captured at a later date and there occurred some greening on earth by time. To me this is a different land cover and hard to fix by applying raster-wide balancing functions.

Comment: PolyGeo, I have the answer to my question, so if you let me, I can demonstrate it.

Comment: @Gary I have reopened your question so you can provide the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I suspected, the almost perfect result cannot be achieved with a single software.

First I used Photoshop Photomerge... function merge the up to 8 images which were created at the same flight.

After I georefered these merged images in ArcMap, so it will have a correct location.

And final and most important step is with ENVI Seamless Mosaic. Which means manually I had to create the lines where the tool mosaics the images together. 
More info: http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/MosaicSeamless.html